# Bad Request Sending HTTP REQUEST

Tags: javascript, java, html, microservices, api-gateway

When I make a gateway request to the URL manually in my project, it gives me the correct data, but when I try to send an http request with the frontend, the API does not work. Why is that?

JavaScript

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById("signupbtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

 
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:9000/user/register?username=${username}&password=${password}");
    xhr.send();
  })

</script>
```

Giving  POST http://localhost:9000/user/register?username=${username}&password=${password} 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Please share the error/problem you encounter, 'does not work' doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: The problem is I ve not encounter any error, it is just not working. I didnt find a answer for this like 7 hour. My question is how can i send http request to api gateway from frontend using button

Comment: Nope, not good enough. "Just not working" simply doesn't give us enough information to help you. You're going to have to figure out *what* isn't working: Is the request being sent from the browser? Arriving at the server? Are you getting a response? Et cetera.

Comment: When I run this url manually http://localhost:9000/user/register?username&password it is working but when I try to send http request via frontend button nothing occur

Comment: 'Nothing occurs' is not possible, something for sure occurs. You run the command `xht.Send()`, debug your code and share with us what happens when the command being executed.

Comment: how can i debug it I dont know how in JavaScript

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/
Once you debug and understand the problem, please edit your post with the details.

Comment: added with image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: occurs now . signup.html:53     POST http://localhost:9000/user/register?username=${username}&password=${password} 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Check if the way you tried to inject the username and password to the url actually works...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your request is incorrect if you want to replace the variables in your template string. You should be using the backtick ` instead of the quote ".

Instead of

```
"http://localhost:9000/user/register?username=${username}&password=${password}"
```

You should be using

```
`http://localhost:9000/user/register?username=${username}&password=${password}`
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if you would be able to send a API request to a gateway from your frontend without any communicator.